# What is the correct way for sharing data among AppWidgetProvider and RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory

Tags: android

Currently, my `AppWidgetProvider` is having a static data. It is used for information passing around `AppWidgetProvider` & `RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory`

```
public class MyAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
    // Key will be widget id
    private static Map<Integer, Holder> holderMap = new java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Holder>();

    public static int getClickedColumn(int appWidgetId) {
        Holder holder = holderMap.get(appWidgetId);  
        if (holder == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        return holder.clickedColumn;
    }
```

---

```
public class AppWidgetRemoteViewsFactory implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {
    @Override
    public void onDataSetChanged() {
        int clickedColumn = MyAppWidgetProvider.getClickedColumn(mAppWidgetId);
```

Calling `AppWidgetProvider`'s static method works fine in most of the situation.

However, sometimes, if I place the widget to home screen, let it be there for few hours. When I come back and scoll the `ListView`, I might get the following error randomly.

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.yccheok.project.gui.widget.AppWidgetRemoteViewsFactory.onDataSetChanged(AppWidgetRemoteViewsService.java:390)
    at android.widget.RemoteViewsService$RemoteViewsFactoryAdapter.onDataSetChanged(RemoteViewsService.java:142)
    at com.android.internal.widget.IRemoteViewsFactory$Stub.onTransact(IRemoteViewsFactory.java:49)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
    at org.yccheok.project.gui.widget.MyAppWidgetProvider.<clinit>(MyAppWidgetProvider.java:564)
```

From `<clinit>`, I suspect `MyAppWidgetProvider` is destroyed by OS? This cause `AppWidgetRemoteViewsFactory` wants to perform class initialization, before calling the static function?

Does this mean, `MyAppWidgetProvider` can be destroyed anytime by OS, and we shouldn't place share-able static data in it?

*If so, what is the correct way for sharing data among `AppWidgetProvider` and `RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory`? (Besides using File, or SharedPreferences)*

Comment: How static is the information you need to share meaning does it change often or is the clicked column set once when the widget starts/initializes?
Also does this data has to be stored in the AppWidgetProvider? What's the nature of this data? Where does it origin from?

Comment: Currently, it records down the UI state. Is the progress button rotating right now? Is the header column being pressed? If yes, which header column. Is the header column suppose to show up arrow or down arrow, ...

Comment: I have a fairly sophisticated mail widget with rotating refresh button, some buttons, icons etc. What I did is manage all the actual list item in the RemoteViewsFactory (they pull their content from a ContentProvider) while all elements that are not strictly part of the list are managed by the AppWidgetProvider. That way they don't really have to share information. If the user presses the refresh button, the widget starts the animation for the progress button while the db runs the query. The list refreshes itself automatically once the db has finished.

Comment: So my question really is if the RemoteViewsFactory should have to know about the elements outside the actual list?

Comment: @EmanuelMoecklin Some row list items, they will be fully managed by RemoteViewsFactory. However, for things like pseudo action bar refresh button (http://i.imgur.com/eWZmr6r.png) animation will be started by AppWidgetProvider. However, actual work (Fetching stock price) being will be performed in RemoteViewsFactory's onDataSetChanged. Before returning from onDataSetChanged, RemoteViewsFactory needs to turn off animated refresh button.

Comment: I do not use any content provider. I merely initialize data structure, by reading disk file in onDataSetChanged. In onDataSetChanged, if I found the data structure is being initialized, I will spawn a thread, to perform data structure stock price updating. My sense told me that, perhaps this is a wrong design...

Comment: @EmanuelMoecklin By the way, a very nicely done mail widget.

Comment: So it's basically the refresh button that needs to be stopped when the list is fully loaded, right (in that case I have a way to do it without using static variables)? What do you need the clicked column for then? What does it do and why do you need to retrieve in in the factory?

Comment: In the clicked column, AppWidgetProvider will turn on a flag to indicate "I wish to sort this column", (I do not perform real sorting operation in AppWidgetProvider as it is not suitable to perform time-consuming task), and then notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged. In RemoteViewsFactory's onDataSetChanged, RemoteViewsFactory will notify such flag. It will then perform real sorting operation on the data structure, and turn off the flag.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**RemoteViewsFactory -> AppWidgetProvider**

The communication from the RemoteViewsFactory to the AppWidgetProvider can be done using Broadcasts, e.g. like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_PROGRESS_OFF);
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

The AppWidgetProvider receives the event like so:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

    // here goes the check if the app widget id is ours

    final String action = intent.getAction();
    if (ACTION_PROGRESS_OFF.equals(action)) {
        // turn off the refresh spinner
```

Of course the broadcast action needs to be defined in the manifest:

```
<receiver
    android:name="...">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        <action android:name="myPackage.ACTION_PROGRESS_OFF" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data ... />
</receiver>
```

---

**AppWidgetProvider -> RemoteViewsFactory**

One way to communicate with the RemoteViewsFactory (and in your case probably the best one) is to send the information in the intent of the service you're passing to the RemoteViewsAdapter:

```
Intent intentRVService = new Intent(context, RemoteViewsService.class);
intentRVService.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);

// let's put in some extra information we want to pass to the RemoteViewsFactory
intentRVService.putExtra("HELLO", "WORLD");

// when intents are compared, the extras are ignored, so we need to
// embed the extras into the data so that the extras will not be ignored
intentRVService.setData(Uri.parse(intentRVService.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));

rv.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetId, R.id.my_list, intentRVService);
rv.setEmptyView(R.id.my_list, android.R.id.empty);

// create the pending intent template for individual list items
...
rv.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.my_list, pendingIntentTemplate);

appWidgetMgr.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetId, R.id.my_list);
```

The RemoteViewsService can easily retrieve the information from the intent and pass it along to the RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory.

I'm not 100% sure when and how your widget decides to sort the data but I'd assume if the user picks a column to sort then you have to go through the update cycle with notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged and then you would pass that column along. If you need that information later on then you'd have to store the information somehow (SharedPreferences).

Comment: "using a broadcast" will not allow your widget to be used when app is not running

Comment: @FindOutIslamNow if a widget is running, then the app is running.

Comment: But how to get the intent from `RemoteViewsFactory`?

Comment: @KimiChiu not sure I understand the question. The AppWidgetProvider receives the intent in "public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent)"

Comment: @EmanuelMoecklin Kimi is asking how to get the intent from RemoteViewsFactory (not the AppWidgetProvider). Once a RemoteViewsFactory has been creating, there seems to be some code that reuses an existing views factory instead of recreating, which means any extras that you update in the intent aren't actually getting to the RemoteViewsFactory. The use-case that I'm personally solving for is trying to update the RemoteViewsFactory from the AppWidgetProvider.

Comment: @EdLee I see. I personally just recreate the RemoteViewsFactory when the widget updates, recreating the views. If that seems to be too expensive (try it before prematurely optimizing...), then you can probably use the LocalBroadcastManager. I haven't tested it myself but I don't see why that wouldn't work.