# Android onReceive not called

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm trying to follow this example:
[What is the correct way for sharing data among AppWidgetProvider and RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22563153/what-is-the-correct-way-for-sharing-data-among-appwidgetprovider-and-remoteviews)

As such, I have a `RemoteViewsFactory` that has this:

```
@Override
public void onDataSetChanged() {
    // Subsequent calls to get the data.
    newsGetter.updateListFeed(null, new NewsGetter.OnUpdateListFeedFinishedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onUpdateListFeedFinished(VolleyError error) {
            //async return here from volley

            Intent widgetUpdateIntent = new Intent(NewsWidgetBase.FEED_UPDATED);
            widgetUpdateIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(widgetUpdateIntent);
        }
    });

    Log.e(TAG, "******************************** onDataSetChanged PROVIDER");
}
```

Then I have an `AppWidgetProvider` that has this:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    final String action = intent.getAction();

    if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE.equals(action)) {
        Log.e("WidgetBase", "******************************** onReceive ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE");
    } else if (FEED_UPDATED.equals(action)) {
        Log.e("WidgetBase", "******************************** onReceive FEED_UPDATED");

        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        int appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
    }

    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}
```

And in the manifest:

```
    <receiver android:name=".widgets.a">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            <action android:name="com.myapp.FEED_UPDATED" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/abc" />
    </receiver>
```

I get the debugger log for `ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE`, but for my own Intent broadcast, it never fires `onReceive` (breakpoint is never even hit). Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your own `Intent broadcast` to work, you have to `register` your `BroadcastReceiver` programmatically. So register your receiver as

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(YourWidgetReceiver, new IntentFilter("your_intent_action"));
```

And then send your broadcast as

```
Intent intent = new Intent("your_intent_action");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent)
```

;

Hope this helps.